# How to use buffer overflow to "skip" to a specific line in the code?

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, buffer, stack-overflow

I'm currently learning about C and trying to find out more about how memory in a stack works, and how gdb can be used to help.

Below is a code snippet of my problem:

```
bool thisEvaluatesToFalse(char* something) {
    return false;
}

void main() {
    char something[10];
    puts("My plan is to input a specific string over 10 characters than will achieve my goal:");
    gets(something);

    if (thisEvaluatesToFalse(something)) {
        puts("If this runs, its a success!");
    }
}
```

The idea is, my success message will **never run** unless I exploit `gets` to input a `something` over 10 characters, causing an overflow that **overwrites the return address of the function to where the success message is**.

I understand I'm supposed to take a look at the assembly code with gdb and look out for an address, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

Could anyone guide me or show me an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope it helps you figure this out. Good luck!

Consider moving `gets` into `thisEvaluatesToFalse` to overwrite the return address pushed by `main` so the return from `thisEvaluatesToFalse` will return to the `puts` of success.

Like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int thisEvaluatesToFalse() {
    char something[10];
    gets(something);
    return 0xdeadbeef;
}

int main() {
    puts("My plan is to input a specific string over 10 characters than will achieve my goal:");
    if (thisEvaluatesToFalse()) {
        puts("If this runs, its a success!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the highlights of working w/ gdb.

```
gcc main.c -fno-stack-protector -ggdb
gdb a.out
(gdb) disass main

   0x0000000100003eeb <+27>:    call   0x100003eb0 <thisEvaluatesToFalse>
   0x0000000100003ef0 <+32>:    cmp    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000100003ef3 <+35>:    je     0x100003f05 <main+53>
   0x0000000100003ef9 <+41>:    lea    0x94(%rip),%rdi        # 0x100003f94
   0x0000000100003f00 <+48>:    call   0x100003f14

# ORIG RETURN ADDRESS IS 0x0000000100003ef0
# EXPLOIT RETURN ADDRESS FOR SUCCESS IS 0x0000000100003ef9

(gdb) break thisEvaluatesToFalse
(gdb) run

(gdb) x/16x $sp
0x7ff7bfeff930: 0x000c8060  0x00000001  0x00003ed0  0x00000001
0x7ff7bfeff940: 0xbfeff960  0x00007ff7  0x00003ef0  0x00000001
0x7ff7bfeff950: 0x00000013  0x00000000  0x000c8060  0x00000000
0x7ff7bfeff960: 0xbfeffa70  0x00007ff7  0x0001552e  0x00000001

# NOTICE THE VALUE AT 0x7ff7bfeff948 IS 0x00003ef0 (ORIG RETURN)
# NOTICE THE VALUE AT 0x7ff7bfeff94C IS 0x00000001 (ORIG RETURN)

(gdb) s
warning: this program uses gets(), which is unsafe.
1234567890AAAABBBBCCCCDDDD

(gdb) x/16x $sp
0x7ff7bfeff930: 0x000c8060  0x32310001  0x36353433  0x30393837
0x7ff7bfeff940: 0x41414141  0x42424242  0x43434343  0x44444444
0x7ff7bfeff950: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x000c8060  0x00000000
0x7ff7bfeff960: 0xbfeffa70  0x00007ff7  0x0001552e  0x00000001

# NOTICE THE VALUE AT 0x7ff7bfeff948 IS 0x43434343 (LETTER C)
# NOTICE THE VALUE AT 0x7ff7bfeff94C IS 0x44444444 (LETTER D)

(gdb) set *0x7ff7bfeff948 = 0x00003ef9
(gdb) set *0x7ff7bfeff94C = 0x00000001
(gdb) x/16x $sp
0x7ff7bfeff930: 0x000c8060  0x32310001  0x36353433  0x30393837
0x7ff7bfeff940: 0x41414141  0x42424242  0x00003ef9  0x00000001

(gdb) s
main () at main.c:17
17          puts("If this runs, its a success!");
(gdb) s
If this runs, its a success!
19      return 0;
```

Leaving it up to you to figure out how to input values for `gets` that perform the actions that replace `C` and `D` with the values you need.

If you can choose a different approach, then instead of using `gets` for the overflow try using `memcpy` and copy more than 10 bytes. Same impact, the stack gets modified.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer! This is really helpful for learning to use gdb better. I just have two questions: 1) In my example above without modifying my `thisEvaluatesToFalse` method, overflowing the buffer only starts to overwrite the hex values after the return address (while your's is before), so there's no way I can input the address during the overflow. 2) How did you tell that the 2nd row, 3rd and 4th column in the `x/16x $sp` command is `0x7ff7bfeff948` and `0x7ff7bfeff94C` from the row header of `0x7ff7bfeff940`? Where did the `8` and the `c` come from? Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't say "no way" but overflow exploits are usually more elaborate than just popping a new return address off the stack. Have a look at [heap-based buffer overflow resulting in code execution](https://rushbnt.github.io/bug%20analysis/netatalk-0day/) and its assigned [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2022-45188)

Comment: The hexdump of the stack pointer register `SP` lists a base address on the left of the colon `0x7ff7bfeff940` each hexadecimal number displayed represents 4 bits, 2 numbers is 8 bits (1 byte) and 8 hexadecimal numbers is 4 bytes, so each value is a 4 byte offset starting from `0x7ff7bfeff940` so:
 `0x7ff7bfeff940 = 0x41414141`
 `0x7ff7bfeff944 = 0x42424242`
 `0x7ff7bfeff948 = 0x43434343`
 `0x7ff7bfeff94C = 0x44444444`